# React - ReactCSSTransitionGroup changing transitionName

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ReactCSSTransitionGroup from here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html
Is there a way to change `transitionName="example"` to have it take an object instead of string? `transitionName={styles.example}`

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples from the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#custom-classes

```
// ...
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName={ {
    enter: 'enter',
    enterActive: 'enterActive',
    leave: 'leave',
    leaveActive: 'leaveActive',
    appear: 'appear',
    appearActive: 'appearActive'
  } }>
  {item}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName={ {
    enter: 'enter',
    leave: 'leave',
    appear: 'appear'
  } }>
  {item2}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
// ...
```